# Getting Postgres to truncate values if necessary?

Tags: postgresql

If I create a table `mytable` with column `data` as `varchar(2)` and then insert something like `'123'` into the column, postgres will give me an error for Value too long for type.

How can I have Postgres ignore this and truncate the value if necessary?

Also, I do not (when creating the query) know the actual size of the `data` column in `mytable` so I can't just cast it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/datatype-character.html), you have to explicitly cast it to achieve this behavior, as returning an error is a requirement of the SQL standard.  Is there no way to inspect the table's schema before creating the query to know what to cast it to?

Comment: Yea, I suppose there is.. just takes more work.. guess it's my only solution though.

Comment: Example would be useful. Does this not apply only to existing table data, as opposed to being applied during COPY?  The page you reference states `If one explicitly casts a value to character varying(n) or character(n), then an over-length value will be truncated to n characters without raising an error`. But I still get error e.g. `value too long for type character varying(50)`..

Answer (score 1):

Use text type with trigger instead:

```
create table mytable (
  data text
);

create or replace function mytable_data_trunc_trigger()
  returns trigger language plpgsql volatile as $$
begin
  NEW.data = substring(NEW.data for 2);
  return NEW;
end;
$$;

create trigger mytable_data_truncate_trigger
  before insert or update on mytable for each row
  execute procedure mytable_data_trunc_trigger();

insert into mytable values (NULL),('1'),('12'),('123');

select * from mytable;
```

```
 data 
------

 1
 12
 12
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Probably quite some overhead for new applications, but a great solution for existing code migrating from other DBs with autotruncation towards Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is just substring

```
INSERT INTO mytable (data) VALUES (substring('123' from 1 for 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the datatype to varchar, and then use a trigger to enforce the two char constraint.